# (Laravel/JQuery UI) : Can't reset <select> and <textarea> on closing dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

I am currently developing an application with Laravel 5.8 version and i use JQuery UI dialog as "pop-up" with some form to add datas in list.

So i have for example this type of form-popup :

```
<div class="dialog" id="addTr" data-open="{{ isset($_GET['popUpTr']) ? $_GET['popUpTr'] : 'close' }}" title="Ajouter une tranche">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('tranches.store') }}">
        @csrf
        <input hidden type="text" name="ID_PROJET" value="{{ isset($projet->ID_PROJET) ? $projet->ID_PROJET : null }}">
        <div class="row minimized">
            <div class="col-3">
                <span>Type contact</span><span class="required-star">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <select name="TYPE_CONTACT_" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="select-typeContactAddTr" required>
                    <option value="">Aucun</option>
                    <!-- si le projet est reservé uniquement aux entreprises (ouverture projet = 2) -->
                    @if($projet->OUVERTURE_ == 2)
                      <option value="1" {{ old('TYPE_CONTACT_') == 1 ? 'selected' : null }}>Entreprises</option>
                    @else
                      @foreach($typesContact as $tp)
                        <option {{ old('TYPE_CONTACT_') == $tp->CLECOD ? 'selected' : null }} value="{{ $tp->CLECOD }}">{{ $tp->LIBCOD }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    @endif
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row minimized">
            <div class="col-3">
                <span>Numéro <span class="text-9">(numérique)</span></span><span class="required-star">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <input name="CPT_TRANCHE" id="input-cptAddTr" maxlength="2" value="{{ old('CPT_TRANCHE') }}" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm {{ $errors->first('CPT_TRANCHE') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row minimized">
            <div class="col-3">
                <span>Libellé</span><span class="required-star">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input name="LIBEL_TR" id="input-libelAddTr" type="text" value="{{ old('LIBEL_TR') }}" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row minimized">
            <div class="col-3">
                <span>De</span><span class="required-star">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input name="MT_SOUTIEN_MINI" id="montant-min-input" type="text" value="{{ old('MT_SOUTIEN_MINI') }}" class="form-control form-control-sm budget-input" required>
                <span>€</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <span>à</span><span class="required-star">*</span>
                <input name="MT_SOUTIEN_MAXI" id="montant-max-input" type="text" value="{{ old('MT_SOUTIEN_MAXI') }}" class="form-control form-control-sm budget-input" required>
                <span>€</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row minimized">
            <div class="col-3">
                <span>Montant réel</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <input name="MT_REEL" id="montant-reel-input" value="{{ old('MT_REEL') }}" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm budget-input">
                <span>€</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row minimized">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info cancel-button" type="reset">Annuler</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The idea is that if the user make an error in the data typing, the datas are returning with the error thanks to the `old` function of Laravel : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#old-input
The problem is that these datas have to be delete when the user close the pop-up or click on the "cancel" button.

So i have create function that load pop up and manage the user action on it. Here is the JS code using JQuery UI (last stable version) :

```js
var loadTrPopUp = function(elementID) {
    $(function() {
        $("#" + elementID).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modale: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 420,
            width: 650,
            closeText:"",
            close: function() {
                console.log("close an reset tranche")
                $('#select-typeContactAddTr option:first').prop('selected',true);
                $("#montant-min-input").attr("value","")
                $("#montant-max-input").attr("value","")
                $("#montant-reel-input").attr("value","")
                $("#input-cptAddTr").attr("value","")
                $("#input-libelAddTr").attr("value","")
            }
        })
    })

    $(function() {
        $(".cancel-button").on('click', function() {
            $("#" + elementID).dialog("close");
        })
    })
}
```

For the simple `<input>` that works great and the field are reinitialize when the user close the pop up. But for others types of field like `<textarea>` or `<select>`, the datas are not reinitialize.

I search on how i can reinitialize these types of input and i have adapted my code but that still not working so i think that the problem come from the `old` function. But i'm not sure so if someone have an idea or can help me that would be great!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just curious, any reason why you're using `DOM ready` inside a function declaration? At what point in your workflow do you call this function, `loadTrPopUp`?

Comment: No specific reason, i call it just one time when the document is loading